# Use of linspace with a range of constant value parameters

Tags: matlab, function, plot, parameters

Consider the function

```
x(t) = C_prey e^{t (A - B C_predator)}
```

and

```
 y(t) = C_predator
```

where `C_prey`, `C_predator`, `A`, `B` are constant value parameters. 
For ease, let `C_prey` = `C_predator` = 10 and `B`=5

To plot these two function together:

I define the range of my values

```
A = transpose(5*[10 20 30 40 50])

t = linspace(0.01,0.05,5)
```

Since I want to determine the plot over the time interval 0.01 to 0.05 for each value of A, I perform an element-wise multiplication to yield

```
t.*A
```

But `plot(t,x)` does not give me the plot I am looking for. I do not understand what is wrong with my method.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You don't want an element wise multiplication of `t` and `A`, you want every element of `A` to be multiplied by every element of `t`.  To achieve that you do not want to take the transpose of A, i.e. you want `A=5*[10 20 30 40 50]`, then you want `t(:)*A`.  Then when you `plot(t,t(:)*A)`, you will get each column of `t(:)*A` as a separate line in your plot.  Similarly to the question you asked earlier.

Comment: @PhilGoddard Thank you very much!
Mathematically, this is just the external direct product of two sets

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like the following?

```
C_predator = 10;
C_prey = 10;
B = 5;
A = transpose(5*[10 20 30 40 50]);
y = @(t)C_predator;
x = (@(t) C_prey*exp(t.*(A - B*C_predator)));

t = linspace(0.01,0.05,5);
figure(1);
plot(t, x(t));grid on;
```

It produces the following output:
[image: Output-1]

If this is what you are looking for then it can also be rewritten as the following where you don't need `linespace` function.

```
figure(2);
fplot((@(t) C_prey*exp(t.*(A' - B*C_predator))), [0.01, 0.05]); grid on;
```

And the output is:
[image: Output-2]